# Customization of custom buttons in Salesforce

Tags: custom-button

I have a question regarding custom buttons in salesforce. I have a requirement that includes can we change the label of a custom button on record page.It should be customizable. It means a user can customize the label by its own and can give any name to the button.

Thanks

Comment: Custom button's label can be easily changed from setup menu. Don't understand your question. Button names cannot be made user specific, at most it can be language specific with help of translation workbench.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, from set up i know but requirement was that,on record we have custom button so user can change the name of custom button directly or from some other place by himself (as a system admin profile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Setup go to `Translation Workbench` -> `Override`, select your Package, the Type `Button and Link Label` and your object, now you can override the label of any Custom Button on that object. (This change affects all users, Only Admins can/should do these changes)

Comment: Ya got your point Rahul, buttons labels directly user can't edit on go.It can only be changed from setup menu.

Comment: LOL @Gauravsingh, who's point did you get :D

Comment: Ya ya i got your point :P